# PL-SQL realizar consulta mediante filtros null o no

Tags: oracle, plsql

hay alguna forma de yo concatenarle a un select un query segun una condicion? por ejemplo en tengo un procedure en el que voy a recibir N parametros de entrada, el query lo tengo listo pero como son filtros no todos los parametros vendran con un valor (se reciben un codigo, fecha desde y fecha hasta), el problema es que en el select que tengo para que me pueda traer la data debo colocarle los valores a todos los parametros, mi pregunta es yo puedo concatenarle mediante un IF si por ejemplo codigo viene lleno le anexo a ese select ese valor y ejecuto?, para que tenga una idea, en java mediante stringQueryBuilder  y la condicion IF, yo puedo agregarle al query mediante .append la condicion de 'and fecha_desde = ?', existe alguna forma en PL o tienen alguna sugerencia?

aca el query

SELECT ORDER_SCHEDULE_NO , S.SUPPLIER, S.SUP_NAME , TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), TO_CHAR(ORDER_CREATE_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM ORDER_SCHEDULE OS, SUPS S WHERE S.SUPPLIER = :SUPPLIER AND TRUNC(order_date) >= TO_DATE(:FECHADESDE,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
AND TRUNC(order_date) <= TO_DATE(:FECHAHASTA,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND S.SUPPLIER = OS.SUPPLIER ORDER BY ORDER_DATE

Answer (score -1):

Si, puedes.

Para ello puedes usar los **SYS_REFCURSOR** que son un tipo especial de cursor que puedes ejecutar a partir de un `VARCHAR2` (una cadena de caracteres vamos). El `VARCHAR2` puedes confeccionarlo a tu gusto usando condicionales `IF`, tal y como indicas.

Un ejemplo práctico:

Creamos un procedure y declaramos nuestras variables de cursor y varchar2:

```
PRUEBA_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
SENTENCIA VARCHAR2(10000);
```

Después vamos confeccionando la sentencia a nuestro gusto:

```
SENTENCIA:= 'SELECT ejemplo FROM ejemploTabla WHERE a = 1';

--Si se cumple la condición siguiente, agregamos un AND al where
IF(condicionEjemplo) THEN
    SENTENCIA := SENTENCIA || 'AND b = 2';
END;
```

Por último, abrimos el cursor, el cual ejecutará la sentencia:

```
OPEN PRUEBA_CURSOR FOR SENTENCIA;
```

Cabe decir que puedes devolver este cursor como **parametro OUT** en el procedure, o incluso puedes ejecutar un loop por cada registro devuelto por la Select.

Comment: gracias amigo, use is null o asigno valor del campo para la solucion